# How do I implement a null coalescing operator in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, null-coalescing-operator

Or how do I make this thing work?

I have an Interval object:

```
class Interval(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'intervals'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    start = Column(DateTime)
    end = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    task_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tasks.id'))

@hybrid_property #used to just be @property
def hours_spent(self):
    end = self.end or datetime.datetime.now()
    return (end-start).total_seconds()/60/60
```

And a Task:

```
class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    intervals = relationship("Interval", backref="task")

@hybrid_property  # Also used to be just @property
def hours_spent(self):
    return sum(i.hours_spent for i in self.intervals)
```

Add all the typical setup code, of course.

Now when I try to do `session.query(Task).filter(Task.hours_spent > 3).all()`

I get `NotImplementedError: <built-in function getitem>` from the `sum(i.hours_spent...` line.

So I was looking at [this part](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#building-custom-comparators) of the documentation and theorized that there might be some way that I can write something that will do what I want. [This part](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#correlated-subquery-relationship-hybrid) also looks like it may be of use, and I'll be looking at it while waiting for an answer here ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is not smart enough to build SQL expression tree from these operands, you have to use explicit `propname.expression` decorator to provide it. But then comes another problem: there is no portable way to convert interval to hours in-database. You'd use `TIMEDIFF` in MySQL, `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ... ) / 3600` in PostgreSQL etc. I suggest changing properties to return `timedelta` instead, and comparing apples to apples.

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func


class Interval(Base):
    ...

    @hybrid_property
    def time_spent(self):
        return (self.end or datetime.now()) - self.start

    @time_spent.expression
    def time_spent(cls):
        return func.coalesce(cls.end, func.current_timestamp()) - cls.start


class Task(Base):
    ...

    @hybrid_property
    def time_spent(self):
        return sum((i.time_spent for i in self.intervals), timedelta(0))

    @time_spent.expression
    def hours_spent(cls):
        return (select([func.sum(Interval.time_spent)])
            .where(cls.id==Interval.task_id)
            .label('time_spent'))
```

The final query is:

```
session.query(Task).filter(Task.time_spent > timedelta(hours=3)).all()
```

which translates to (on PostgreSQL backend):

```
SELECT task.id AS task_id, task.title AS task_title 
FROM task 
WHERE (SELECT sum(coalesce(interval."end", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - interval.start) AS sum_1 
FROM interval 
WHERE task.id = interval.task_id) > %(param_1)s
```

Answer (score 34):

For a simple example of SQLAlchemy's coalesce function, this may help: [Handling null values in a SQLAlchemy query - equivalent of isnull, nullif or coalesce](http://progblog10.blogspot.com/2014/06/handling-null-values-in-sqlalchemy.html).

Here are a couple of key lines of code from that post:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import coalesce
my_config = session.query(Config).order_by(coalesce(Config.last_processed_at, datetime.date.min)).first()
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use the text function and could not use 0 as an integer.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

session.query(sa.func.coalesce(table1.col1, sa.text("0"))).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete example of making a func action similar to `coalesc` or `nvl`.

Note how it takes in arguements, and renders an expression... in this case NVL(a, b) when used with Oracle.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html#subclassing-guidelines

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import FunctionElement

class coalesce(FunctionElement):
     name = 'coalesce'

@compiles(coalesce)
def compile(element, compiler, **kw):
     return "coalesce(%s)" % compiler.process(element.clauses)

@compiles(coalesce, 'oracle')
def compile(element, compiler, **kw):
     if len(element.clauses) > 2:
          raise TypeError("coalesce only supports two arguments on Oracle")
     return "nvl(%s)" % compiler.process(element.clauses)
```

Then when you want to use it...

```
from my_oracle_functions_sqla import coalesce
select([coalesce(A.value, '---')])  # etc
```

Hope that helps.