# How do I subtract datetimes in SQLite+SQLalchemy?

Tags: sqlite, datetime, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlite+sqlalchemy and I'm doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18102848/344286) and I get some sql that looks like this:

```
SELECT task.id as task_id, task.title AS task_title
FROM task
WHERE (SELECT sum(coalesce(intervals."end", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - intervals.start) AS sum_1
FROM intervals
WHERE task.id = intervals.task_id) > :param_1
```

The problem is that this doesn't work because my query actually needs to look like this:

```
...
WHERE (SELECT sum(julianday(coalesce(intervals."end", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) - julianday(intervals.start)) AS sum_1
...
```

but I haven't been able to find a julianday function in SQLAlchemy, or exactly how to hand-alter the query.

How can I alter the behavior so that I can actually get the difference of these values in sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy has no need to define explicitly every function found in every database engine. It knows about a few standard ones, but you can use `sqlalchemy.func.foobar(arg1, arg2, ...)` and it will be translated to function call `foobar(arg1, arg2, ...)` in SQL. Change

```
@time_spent.expression
def time_spent(cls):
    return func.coalesce(cls.end, func.current_timestamp()) - cls.start
```

to

```
@time_spent.expression
def time_spent(cls):
    return func.julianday(func.coalesce(cls.end, func.current_timestamp())) - \
           func.julianday(cls.start)
```

and you should be fine. Stuck with SQLite because `julianday` is not portable, though.

Comment: Ah! Perfect - I actually was exposed to this when I mistyped `coalesce` as `coalesc` - but I completely put it out of my mind.